# Rails session doesn't saved during ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, session, jquery, session-cookies

I have this ajax call after completing specific action

```
  $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: $("#myform").prop('action'),
              data: $("#myform").serialize(),
              xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
              beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').last().attr('content'));
              }
          });
```

this ajax call refering to create action, so I wanna save the params of the form in the session I've created before. so I put this in create action

```
 def create
      session[:my_session].deep_merge!(params[:user])
      puts session[:my_session]
```

I print the session to make sure from the server that it contains the right params, and Yeah, it has been printed with the right values.

```
{"profile_id"=>"1000", "first_name"=>"john", "last_name"=>"vieira", "email"=> "john@sandsora.com"}
```

the problem here is after that call, the session doesn't save the data which I've stored!, which means that it stored the latest data before this assignment. I searched for that error and I got that it may be CSRF token error and I fixed it by adding `beforeSend` function, but I still have the same problem, so any suggestions please?

Comment: how are you determining that the session didn't store correctly?

Comment: @MikeCampbell printed the session in the server console, and it looks has right values

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that the session cookie headers are not being set. Without this cookie  rails has not way of setting the correct session and you data is "lost" after the request has completed. Your browser should send it automatically on your ajax requests though...

Can you verify that the session cookie is being sent with your ajax request?

Comment: Check in your browser. In Chrome you should be able to look under the Network tab in the developer tools. See what request and response data is in your ajax request.